# How to remove all documents of type from elasticsearch index version 2.2

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to remove all documents of a specific type using the nodejs client for elastic search.

I have this code:

```
var deleteType = function (type, done) {
    client().indices.delete({
      "index": settings.index,
      "type": type,
      "ignore": [404]
    }, function (error, response) {
      if (error) {
        logger.error(error, 'Failed to delete index type');
        done(error);
      } else {
        logger.debug({"res": response}, "deleted %s index", type);
        done();
      }
    });
  };
```

The type and index parameters are fine. But it seems to be deleting the entire index, not just docs of that type. I'm guessing that I've made the wrong API call with `indices.delete`.

What is the right way to delete all documents of a specific "type" within an index?

Comment: What version of ES? I believe they removed this functionality sometime in the 2.x...I'll double check before I answer. It's essentially the same as delete by query which I think they moved to a plugin

Comment: latest version 2.2 - I think that's the case, deleting the mapping would have been fine in my case too, but they deprecated that too! :) I'll look into the delete by query plugin I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prior to version 2.0, you can delete a type in an index using the [Delete Mapping as part of the Indices API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/indices-delete-mapping.html).

> Allow to delete a mapping (type) along with its data. The REST
>   endpoints are
>
> [DELETE] /{index}/{type}
>
> [DELETE] /{index}/{type}/_mapping
>
> [DELETE] /{index}/_mapping/{type}

As of version 2.0, Elasticsearch no longer supports this directly. The [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/indices-delete-mapping.html) explains it like this:

> It is no longer possible to delete the mapping for a type. Instead you
>   should delete the index and recreate it with the new mappings.

However, this functionality is made available by the [Delete By Query Plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.0/plugins-delete-by-query.html).

> The delete-by-query plugin adds support for deleting all of the
>   documents (from one or more indices) which match the specified query.
>   It is a replacement for the problematic delete-by-query functionality
>   which has been removed from Elasticsearch core.

Simply construct a query that filters for the type in your index you want to delete, and use that as the basis for your "Delete By Query".

Comment: Thanks Brooke, I just added a second part to the question, which is how to invoke it, but I found the answer already, there's an NPM extension to the node client here [https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch-deletebyquery] - cheers.

Comment: @RichardG you're welcome, glad you found what you needed! Best of luck to you ~